# How to instantiate class using a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

In TypeScript, I saw in other discussions that there should be a way to create a class whose type depends on a variable.

For instance, if we have . . .

```
class MyClass {    
   someFunc(){alert("Hello");}    
}
var myClassName = "MyClass";
```

The answers supposedly were either:

Answer #1:
`var myClassInstance = new (<any>window)[myClassName]();`

Answer #2:
`var myClassInstance = Object.create(window[myClassName]);`

I'm trying these in my console, but neither works for me.
For #1, I get error messages: "Syntax Error," or if I omit `<any>` then "Object doesn't support this action".
For #2, I get error messages: "Object.create: argument is not an Object and is not null"

Does anyone have any ideas why these aren't working for me, and/or how I can instantiate a class in Typescript based on the value of a variable that holds the class name? Thank you!

Comment: `class`/`let` and `const` aren't like the old `function` and `var` that can "polute" the global namespace (window in your case) ... when you say "the answers supposedly were" ... according to who?

Comment: @JaromandaX My bad. Did not real the question correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with `class` - you'd have to use an ES5 constructor:

```js
function MyClass() {}
MyClass.prototype.someFunc = function() {
  alert("Hello!");
};
var myClassName = "MyClass";
var myClassInstance = new window[myClassName]();
myClassInstance.someFunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason those "answers" don't work is because `MyClass` is not a property of the global object (window in your case)

This is true with variables declared in the global scope using `let` and `const` as well

However, since you seem to be willing to switch to old school definition, i.e. willing to rewrite the class definitions, you can always use this instead - with the bonus that there is minimal rewrite involved

### Note: use `var` not `let` or `const`

```
var MyClass = class MyClass {    
   someFunc(){alert("Hello");}
}
var AnotherClass = class AnotherClass {    
   someFunc(){alert("Hello again");}
}
var YetAnotherClass = class YetAnotherClass {    
   someFunc(){alert("Hello once more");}
}
```

Then you can simply

```
let instance = new window[myClassName]();
```

Also, depending on where/how the classes are defined (in an import?), it may actually be required to do something like

```
window.MyClass = class MyClass {    
   someFunc(){alert("Hello");}
}
```

instead

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I was hoping to instantiate classes on the fly, just by providing a variable with the name of the class, without having to pre-load any constants, constructors, or other code, so that if in the future I add new classes, or change the structure (properties) of an existing class, my code would handle that seamlessly at run-time, without me having to rewire any other code. But I'm starting to think that may be an unrealistic goal for now.

Comment: @Crowdpleasr - I've updated the answer given you are willing to rewrite the definitions of the classes